# Mobile accelerometers and gyroscopes check feature

Tags: javascript, android, iphone

I'm looking for a proper way to check if accelerometers and gyroscopes is available on mobile device ( mostly android & iphone ) in javascript.

Maybe by trying to figure out if the function called return something ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
if (window.DeviceMotionEvent) {
  window.addEventListener('devicemotion', deviceMotionHandler, false);
} else {
  // This device doesn't support accelerators
}

function deviceMotionHandler(e) {
    var acceleration = e.accelerationIncludingGravity;
    var accelerationX = acceleration.x;
    var accelerationYe.acceleration.y;
    var accelerationZ = acceleration.z;

    if (e.rotationRate) {
      var rotation = e.rotationRate;
      var rotationAlpha = rotation.alpha;
      var rotationBeta = rotation.beta;
      var rotationGamma = rotation.gamma;
    }
}
```

[This](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/device/orientation/) article will shed more light upon the issue.